# Group by help ( grouping by multiple, have duplicates)

Tags: mysql, date, time, group-by, grouping

SO i have a task and i need to group my results by Date and by Provider_name but currently my code is listing out multiple dates and Providers. (need to have one provider per day (25 days in all) so my table shows how many messages the provider got that day and how much did they earn)

This needs to be my result. [Result table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Op8u.png)

[But this is what i'm currently getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1uSRL.png)

This is my code currently

```
SELECT date_format( time, '%Y-%m-%d' ) AS Date, provider_name, COUNT( message_id ) AS Messages_count, SUM( price ) AS Total_price
FROM mobile_log_messages_sms
INNER JOIN service_instances ON service_instances.service_instance_id =   mobile_log_messages_sms.service_instance_id
INNER JOIN mobile_providers ON mobile_providers.network_code = mobile_log_messages_sms.network_code
WHERE time
BETWEEN '2017-02-26 00:00:00'
AND time
AND '2017-03-22 00:00:00'
AND price IS NOT NULL
AND price <> ''
AND service IS NOT NULL
AND service <> ''
AND enabled IS NOT NULL
AND enabled >=1
GROUP BY provider_name, time
ORDER BY time DESC
```

Can you tell me where i've messed up, i really can't figure out the answer.

Comment: you are grouping time which will group the result by day including hour, minute and second so that is why you getting different count from same day. Try grouping by day instead.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```
    ....

    GROUP BY provider_name, date_format( time, '%Y-%m-%d' )
    ORDER BY time DESC
```

You are grouping time which will group the result by time including hour, minute and second so on ... that is why you getting different count from same day. Try grouping by day instead.

Comment: woow. you beat me :)

Comment: ;) you understand the reason?

Answer (score 0):

`time` column is `datetime`. So its grouped by date and time both rather than just date.

Change GROUP BY statement to

```
GROUP BY provider_name, date_format( time, '%Y-%m-%d' )
```